# How to add Jenkins bot and other checker bots in github?

Tags: github, jenkins, bots, jenkins-workflow

Recently, I've met several bots in Google TensorFlow git repos.

When I submit a PR, one TF bot finds some related groups for the PR and says, "Can one of admins verify this patch?"

Then, one of a verifier bot says, I need to signup something, and I left a comment, Done. Then, the bot checked and marked it was done.

Then, later one admin commented, "jenkins, test please." I guess this triggers Jenkins and reports the test and other checker results.

How could I setup the (bot)environment and github workflow like this?

[image]
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/1838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to learn a continuous integration tool like jenkins. Jenkins has triggers to find such events. After events like below triggered. You can use variety of plugins to accomplish very different tasks.

- Source Code commit
- Source Code push
- Poll bug tracker periodically.

For example

- [Jenkins twitter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Twitter+Plugin)
- [Jenkins github plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin)

There are a lot of different plugins for jenkins. See them [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins).

Answer (score 0):

They use this plugin in jenkins : 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

All how to configure is given on the page

Comment: Please also describe the contents of the link in your answer, that way if the link goes bad, your answer will still be good.